# Magento2 Custom Product Type has no Swatch Image

Tags: magento2, swatches

I have added custom product types that are based on the simple product and this works.

However I don't get a swatch image option. I can set base, small_image and thumbnail but no swatch. What have I missed?

I have also tried to specifically add 'swatch_image' in my installer but still no joy.